# Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Trying to plot a solution to an ODE, get an error

Tags: matlab

So I have a code that is as below

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

syms y(x) ys1 ys2;
double eps;
ode = diff(y)+y-sin(x)-cos(x) == 0;
cond1 = y(0) == 1;
ySol1(x) = dsolve(ode,cond1);

ys1=char(ySol1(x));
fprintf('The analytical solution is %s\n', ys1);

figure 
fplot(ys1,'r');

hold on
for eps=-1:0.1:1
    cond2 = y(0) == 1 + eps;
    ySol2(x) = dsolve(ode,cond2);
    ys2=char(ySol2(x));
    fprintf('The perturbed solution is %s\n', ys2);
    plot(ys2, 'b');
end
hold off
```

And I keep on getting the mistake:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in fplot (line 95)
xmin = min(lims(1:2)); xmax = max(lims(1:2));
```

I have tried to change the borders, make it into a matrix and the error is still there. I thought that maybe the second part of the code was the problem, so i deleted it, and the error still kept on showing up. I just don't know what else I can do to make it go. By the way, the original question was

> Solve the perturbed form of the given IVP, then plot all solutions
>   together for different values of the perturbation term ε=[-1,1] with
>   0.1 steps for a suitable x _interval. If possible, check their stability analytically.   y'(x)=-y(x)+sinx+cosx, y(0)=1

Edit: The code for the fplot function is

```
function [x0,y0] = fplot(varargin)

[cax,args,nargs] = axescheck(varargin{:});

error(nargchk(2,inf,nargs,'struct'));

fun  = args{1};
lims = args{2};
args = args(3:end);

if (isvarname(fun))
   fun = ezfcnchk(fun);
else
   fun = fcnchk(fun);
end

marker = '-';
tol = 2e-3;
N = 1;
if nargs >= 3 && ~isempty(args{1})
  if ischar(args{1})
    marker = args{1};
  elseif args{1} < 1
    tol = args{1};
  else
    N = args{1};
  end
end
if nargs >= 4 && ~isempty(args{2})
  if ischar(args{2})
    marker = args{2};
  elseif args{2} < 1
    tol = args{2};
  else 
    N = args{2};
  end
end
if nargin >= 5 && ~isempty(args{3})
  if ischar(args{3})
    marker = args{3};
  elseif args{3} < 1
    tol = args{3};
  else
    N = args{3};
  end
end

xmin = min(lims(1:2)); xmax = max(lims(1:2));
maxstep = (xmax - xmin) / N;
minstep = min(maxstep,(xmax - xmin) * tol);
tryVal = minstep;

x = xmin; y = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});

xx = x;
x = xmin+minstep; y(2,:) = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});
xx(2) = x;

if length(lims) == 4
  ymin = min(lims(3:4)); ymax = max(lims(3:4));
  ylims = 1;
else
  J = find(isfinite(y));
  if isempty(J)
    ymin = 0; ymax = 0;
  else
    ymin = min(y(J)); ymax = max(y(J));
  end
  ylims = 0;
end
ytol = (ymax - ymin) * tol;

I = 2;
while xx(I) < xmax
  I = I+1;

  tryVal = min(maxstep,min(2*tryVal, xmax-xx(I-1)));
  x = xx(I-1) + tryVal;
  y(I,:) = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});

  ylin = y(I-1,:) + (x-xx(I-1)) * (y(I-1,:)-y(I-2,:)) / (xx(I-1)-xx(I-2));

  while any(abs(y(I,:) - ylin) > ytol) && (tryVal > minstep)
    tryVal = max(minstep,0.5*tryVal);
    x = xx(I-1) + tryVal;
    y(I,:) = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});
    ylin = y(I-1,:) + (x-xx(I-1)) * (y(I-1,:)-y(I-2,:)) / (xx(I-1)-xx(I-2));
  end

  if ~ylims
    J = find(isfinite(y(I,:)));
    if ~isempty(J)
      ymin = min(ymin,min(y(I,J))); ymax = max(ymax,max(y(I,J)));
      ytol = (ymax - ymin) * tol;
    end
  end

  xx(I) = x;
end

if nargout == 0
  cax = newplot(cax);
  plot(xx,y,marker,'parent',cax)
  set(cax,'XLim',[xmin xmax]);
  if ylims
    set(cax,'YLim',[ymin ymax]);
  end
else
  x0 = xx.'; y0 = y;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matlab says, error is inside the fplot function. Your "lims" variable is probably empty or has just one element (you are trying to access element 2 in lims(1:2)). Put a breakpoint inside fplot and check the value of lims, it will be easier for you to find the problem then. 
If you need more help you will have to post the code of fplot.